Connecting two W5500 via UDP results in PHY link off
I want to connect two STM32F4 and to communicate via UDP. At the moment I only want to send data from one to another mcu. I have tested tx and rx communication separately with PC - python scripts and I it works as expected. Also, I trace communication with Wireshark.
Now it comes moment where I need to connect mcus with ethernet cable so no more connection with PC. I have problem that PHY link is off on both W5500 and I don’t understand what can be issue. Mac, IP address, port are properly configured. Does anybody have idea what can be problem?
With function wizphy_getphylink() and with orange/green no activity I notice this problem.
Here is init of UDP:
W5500_spi_Hw_Rst(); // reset W5500 by activating nRST pin
W5500_spi_Reg_Spi_Cb_Funcs();      // register different SPI callback functions for wiznet API lib
W5500_spi_Init_Socket_Buff_Size(); // initialize tx and rx buffer size for each socket
W5500_spi_Config_Net_Params();     // configure network parameters
W5500_spi_Config_Net_Phy();        // configure network phy (physical layer)
W5500_spi_Init_UDP_Socket();       // get free socket and declare it to be UDP type

Are you connecting the boards directly to each other or via a network switch?
W5500 does not support auto MDIX so you may have to use a crossover cable if you connect the boards directly.
I recommend trying the links with a network switch in the middle.
